# If Statement is not processing the variable properly even though the variable is appearing correctly

Tags: c, if-statement

I have the following piece of code that calls a function to return the number of moves the player shall receive. This function accepts a char variable being T in this case.

```
    printf("Number Of Moves: %d\n\n", getRoll('T'));
```

This function then generates a random number between 1 and 10 which then goes through an if statement. My issue is that the if statement isn't working and I am not sure why. I have printed the random variable before the if statement and it is working correctly being a number between 1 and 10.

(I also realize there is currently only one case in my switch statement but there will be others.)

```
int getRoll(char letter) {

    int num = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    char plyr = letter;
    int numMoves;

    switch (plyr) {
        case 'T':
            printf("This is the random number: %d", num);// This is working
            if (1 <= num <= 5) {
                numMoves = 3;
            } else if (6 <= num <= 7) {
                numMoves = -6;
            } else if (8 <= num <= 10) {
                numMoves = 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return numMoves;
}
```

Comment: Constructs like `6 <= num <= 7` are not doing what you think they are doing. In C it is written as `6 <= num && num <= 7`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks, that was the issue!

Comment: Make sure that you end diagnostic printing messages with a newline so that the material appears properly.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
(1 <= num <= 5)
```

It actually parses as:

```
((1 <= num) <= 5)
```

So first `1 <= num` is evaluated, resulting in either 0 or 1.  Then the result is compared with 5, i.e. `0 <= 5` or `1 <= 5`.  Both are true so the expression is always true.

You need two separate comparisons here, separated by a logical AND

```
(1 <= num && num <= 5)
```

You'll need to make a similar fix for `(6 <= num <= 7)` and `(8 <= num <= 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Just a little thing you did there.
When you write X< num < y it does not compare the three numbers with eachother, try using and operator there.

```
 if (1 <= num && num <= 5) {
                numMoves = 3;
            } else if (6 <= num && num <= 7) {
                numMoves = -6;
            } else if (8 <= num && num <= 10) {
                numMoves = 1;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression for example in this if statement:

```
if (1 <= num <= 5) {
```

may be equivalently rewritten like:

```
if ( ( 1 <= num ) <= 5) {
```

According to the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 6 Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than
> or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) **shall yield 1 if the
> specified relation is true and 0 if it is false**. The result has type
> int.

Thus as the value of the variable `num` is always greater or equal to 1 due to its initialization

```
int num = (rand() % 10) + 1;
```

then the sub-expression `( 1 <= num )` always evaluates to the integer value `1` according to the quote from the C Standard. And in fact you have:

```
if ( 1 <= 5) {
```

This means that the whole expression of the if statement also always evaluates to logical true.

So the if statement evaluates to true independent of the value stored in the variable `num`.

It is evident that in this if statement and other similar if statements you want to use the logical AND operator like

```
if ( 1 <= num && num <= 5) {
```

that for readability can be written also like

```
if ( ( 1 <= num ) && ( num <= 5 ) ) {
```

Thus you will have

```
if ( ( 1 <= num ) && ( num <= 5 ) ) {
    numMoves = 3;
} else if ( ( 6 <= num ) && ( num <= 7 ) ) {
    numMoves = -6;
} else if ( ( 8 <= num ) && ( num <= 10 ) ) {
    numMoves = 1;
}
```

As the `num` is always greater than or equal to 1 then you may rewrite the if statements also the following simplified way

```
if ( num <= 5 ) {
    numMoves = 3;
} else if ( num <= 7 ) {
    numMoves = -6;
} else if ( num <= 10 ) {
    numMoves = 1;
}
```